# How do I call my Python function?

Tags: python

Here is my assignment:

> Write a program to calculate the credit card balance after one year if
>   a person only pays the minimum monthly payment required by the credit
>   card company each month.
>
> The following variables contain values as described below:
>
> balance - the outstanding balance on the credit card
>
> annualInterestRate - annual interest rate as a decimal
>
> monthlyPaymentRate - minimum monthly payment rate as a decimal
>
> For each month, calculate statements on the monthly payment and
>   remaining balance, and print to screen something of the format:
>
> Month: 1
>   Minimum monthly payment: 96.0
>   Remaining balance: 4784.0
>
> Finally, print out the total amount paid that year and the remaining
>   balance at the end of the year in the format:
>
> It should not specify the values for the variables balance,
>   annualInterestRate, or monthlyPaymentRate - our test code will define
>   those values before testing your submission.

And here is the code I wrote:

```
def minpayment(balance, annualInterestRate, monthlyPaymentRate):
     totalPaid = 0
     month = 1
     while month <= 12:
         minPayment = monthlyPaymentRate * balance 
         balance -=  minPayment 
         balance += (annualInterestRate/12.0)*balance
         print 'Month:',month 
         print 'Minimum monthly payment:',round(minPayment,2) 
         print 'Remaining balance:',round(balance,2) 
         totalPaid += minPayment 
         month += 1
     print 'Total paid:', round(totalPaid,2) 
     print 'Remaining balance:', round(balance,2)
```

Now, my question is, now that I've created the function, how do I call it?

Comment: So wait- you managed to learn how to make a function without figuring out how to call it somewhere along the line? How do you know it works?

Comment: I was surprised too, especially since they were able to call the `round` function.

Comment: As a side note, all of the information about your assignment is not relevant to the question.  You've already completed the assignment, you just wanted to know how to use it.

Comment: Instead of a `while` loop, why not use a `for` since you know how many times through the loop you need?

Answer (score 3):

You can call it like:

```
minpayment(10000, 0.1, 0.3)
```

or in general:

```
# You can modify the values below
balance = 10000
annualInterestRate = 0.1
monthlyPaymentRate = 0.3

minpayment(balance, annualInterestRate, monthlyPaymentRate)
```

Comment: How do I allow it to be any value?

Comment: Christian's second example illustrates this, @user3375872. Instead of setting `balance`, `annualInterestRate`, and `monthlyPaymentRate` to hard-coded values, as he has, use the same-named variables you're using in your code.